# formatting Regex to output a more clean result

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex pattern and sample text below:

```
string pattern = @"Seq No:\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d+)|Purchase Order\n(\d+)|(\d{4}-\d{3}-D\d{3,4})|EA\s+(.*?)\s+Drawing|Due: Requester:\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+[A-Z]{3}|Due:\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+Requester:|Requester:\s([A-Z]{3})|\d.\d{2}\s\d.\d{2}\s(.*?)\sEA";
```

**Sample PO Text Below:**

```
xx
37764
PO Date: 5/24/2023
To: Ship To:
xxx
Total Purchase Order 0.00
PO Terms
Freight Terms:
Ship Via: FOB:
Terms:
N/A
Net 30 Days Best Way Destination
Line Quantity Item Unit Price Amount
U/M
1 1.00 2772-212-W02 0.00 0.00
EA CATCH PAN WELDMENT
Drawing: OPT
Due: Requester:
07/24/2023 GAF
Order: 2853IF-216-703 Seq No: 4
2 2.00 2853-220-D002 0.00 0.00
EA ROLL CART CONTACT PLATE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-220-000 Seq No: 4
3 4.00 MCRI-0100-D0104 0.00 0.00
ROBOT BASE CORNER JACK PLATE 
EA
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-216-702 Seq No: 5
4 4.00 MCRI-0100-D0105 0.00 0.00
EA ROBOT BASE CENTER JACK PLATE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-216-702 Seq No: 6
5 2.00 MCRI-0450-D0103 0.00 0.00
EA LIGHT CURTAIN POST JACK PLATE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-240-000 Seq No: 6
xxxxx(page ended here)
xxxxx(start of next page here)
37764
PO Date: 5/24/2023
To: Ship To:
Purchaser:
xx
USA
Total Purchase Order 0.00
PO Terms
Freight Terms:
Ship Via: FOB:
Terms:
N/A
Net 30 Days Best Way Destination
Line Quantity Item Unit Price Amount
U/M
6 1.00 MCRI-0650-D0202 0.00 0.00
EA 2.5" SCH40 DRESS OUT TUBE
Drawing:
OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-216-702 Seq No: 10
7 2.00 2799-216-D005 0.00 0.00
EA ALUMINUM TUBE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-218-000 Seq No: 11
8 1.00 MCRI-0750-D0101 0.00 0.00
EA TEACH PENDANT MOUNT
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-216-702 Seq No: 12
9 1.00 2853-217-D001 0.00 0.00
EA MOUNTING PLATE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-217-000 Seq No: 12
10 1.00 2799-216-D006 0.00 0.00
ALUMINUM TUBE
EA
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
xx(end of page 2 here in middle of line item 10)
Page 2 of 3
xxx
37764
PO Date: 5/24/2023
To: Ship To:
Purchaser:
xx
USA
Total Purchase Order 0.00
PO Terms
Freight Terms:
Ship Via: FOB:
Terms:
N/A
Net 30 Days Best Way Destination
Line Quantity Item Unit Price Amount
U/M
Order: 2853IF-218-000 Seq No: 12
11 4.00 2799-216-D007 0.00 0.00
EA VACUUM CUP MOUNT
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-218-000 Seq No: 13
12 7.00 2799-216-D008 0.00 0.00
EA BEAM CROSS CLAMP
Drawing:
OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-218-000 Seq No: 14
13 2.00 2853-219-D001 0.00 0.00
EA CYLINDER MOUNT PLATE
Drawing: OPT
Due: 07/24/2023 Requester: GAF
Order: 2853IF-219-000 Seq No: 14
Total 0.00
 xx
 Page 3 of 3
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q52mJs/1

What I have here is a purchase order from a company. and I extract some basic info. but the data is not extracted correctly. When viewed on excel each line item on the PO should be one row in excel but its breaking them up by each match i think from the regex. which is exactly what I am telling it to do I am sure. How can I get the desired result? I'm quite positive its because I'm using a bunch of "|" in my pattern which means "or". I just do not know how else to format the pattern to accurately extract data.

side quest available: Qty is only showing up on 1 entry because qty is presented in 2 different ways which makes it come out as 2 groups. how can i capture both in 1 group?

[image]

original PO screenshot (info hidden)
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a proper CSV parser, like CsvHelpers or `TextFieldParser`. regex is just the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Totally possible. this is the first project I've had that required parsing like this. However it seems very doable, I just don't know the syntax well enough to know what other options I have.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, you could even do it in Assembler or FORTRAN if you really wanted. But why would you when someone has done all the work already?

Comment: Yea I understand what you mean. I'll check out what you mentioned. maybe it will save me some headaches. And I meant totally possible as in I'm not using the proper tool by the way, wasn't saying you were saying otherwise! Thanks!

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Fair enough, I only looked at the screenshot. But then I wonder how reliable the format is anyway.

Comment: What's the actual input format? Is the PO an OCRed Image or something else? Can you post an example input (redacted for information security).

Comment: Hint: If you later on need to ingest POs from other customers, too, you won't want to taylor this too much to one specific one.

Comment: I used clipboard.setText to get sample data from the actual PO. so the text on the regex site is exactly what the program will see. it is a digital PDF it is not a scanned image or anything like that which i think is what OCR is. ill edit a redacted image to the original post though.

Comment: @Fildor We get an obscene amount of  PO's from this specific customer, and they get special things done only to their jobs so thats why its so tailored. I'd love to make one that encapsulates all incoming PO's but its impossible. this would knock out a huge amount of work though.

Comment: _" I'd love to make one that encapsulates all incoming PO's but its impossible. this would knock out a huge amount of work though."_ - I was just asking because that's exactly the industry I have been working in since ~4 years ago. There are companies _specializing_ in exactly that. Using a whole bunch of technologies that are thrown against those POs ... including OCR (Character Recognition), different Extraction Algorithms and even AI.

Comment: sounds really interesting. I program CNC machines for a small manufacturer(~20 people), with pretty small budgets, so I tend to try and homebrew stuff to work from time to time.

Comment: And here's what I would suggest trying: 1. **Get rid of noise, first.** Throw away anything before the captions line and below the line items. 2. **Divide and conquer** Split the line items into individual line items. For example: They always start with the line item number and a whitespace and the last line starts with "Order:" . 3. If you have 1.+2. then attack each line item. They may have subtle differences and specialties you can detect. But it's much easier if you can focus.

Comment: Sometimes it's even easier if you do have OCR-Metadata. Then you can do positional algorithms, too.

Comment: but still the question is how can I condense the data for each line item into 1 row in excel? with all the "or" characters in the pattern it makes a ton of matches which seperates the pieces of each line. thats my biggest issue. i think i can work out the smaller details after that.

Comment: First step is recognition. Output is second. Now the first line pretty much corresponds to the caption line. It's Line Item No, Quantity, Some Item Identifier, Unit Price and Amount.

Comment: Second line starts off with the overflow of the first line, which is the unit. Followed by an item description. And then you have 3 lines of "key: value", basically.

Comment: So, you can recognize that and then flatten the data, then add the "header" data (which is common to each line, e.g. customer, order date, ...)

Comment: Oh, and because you are probably thinking "Come OOOON, this cannot be _that_ complex!" - It **is**. Automatically recognizing POs, Invoices etc is _really non-trivial_. As I said, I worked with software that even used AI, that we would train for customers. And still, it wouldn't be 100% perfect all the time. One option to make this transaction safer would be to agree with the customer to use a standard business information interchange format. Like in Europe, we have ZUGFeERD or XRechung (obviously Germany :D) and I am sure there is something for your business area.

Comment: ^^ And creating Orders and Invoices using those is sometimes as easy as setting a switch in the ERP software. Sometimes you need a paid module, but it really pays off.

Comment: I appreciate everything you brought to the discussion. much to consider. thanks!

Comment: Pfff my english ... _" I have been working in since ~4 years ago."_ - it should be "up until 4 years ago". I did the job about 6 years.

Comment: If the PDF has actual text then it's probably best to just pull that out using a PDF extractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing things in several steps:

1. Extract the interesting part of content, which seems to be about between
   `U/M` and `Total` with a regex like `@"\r?\nU/M\r?\n(?<data>.*)\r?\nTotal\s[\d.]+"s`.
   It may have to be changed to handle multipage output. Here I see only
   *Page 1 of 1*.
   Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/nf0N7z/1
2. Then, for the second part, we can see that each item is always starting
   with the line, quantity, item unit, price and amount. The only thing that
   changes a bit is the order of the item name, due date and requester.
   So, to make it clearer, add some comments in your regex with the `x` flag.
   I'll also use the `m` flag so that `^` and `$` respectively match the
   begin or end of a line.

   The pattern:

   ```
   @"# Match a line such as 1 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
   ^
   (?<line>\d+)\s+
   (?<quantity>[\d.]+)\s+
   (?<item_unit>\d+-\d+-D\d+)\s+ # Will it always be D*** ? If not then change this.
   (?<price>[\d.]+)\s+
   (?<amount>[\d.]+)\s+

   # Match the item name (before or after EA)
   (?:
     EA\s(?<item_name_v1>[^\r\n]*)\s+
     |
     (?<item_name_v2>[^\r\n]*)\nEA\s+
   )

   # Match the drawing
   Drawing:\s+(?<drawing>[^\r\n]+)\s+

   # Match the due date and requester, in several ways
   Due:\s+
   (?:
     Requester:\s+(?<req_date_v1>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?<req_name_v1>[^\r\n]+)
     |
     (?<req_date_v2>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\sRequester:\s+(?<req_name_v2>[^\r\n]+)
   )
   \s+
   Order:\s+(?<order>\w+-\d+-\d+)\s+
   Seq\sNo:\s+(?<seq_no>\d+)
   $
   "gxm
   ```

   Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/hEjKt6/2

As you have multiple syntaxes (I mean different orders of elements), you'll
have multiple capturing groups for the same information. I named these groups
for clarity (instead of just numerical indexes). You could just test the
content of both of them, and take the one which isn't empty, like this
JavaScript example:

```js
// In JavaScript, the x flag isn't handled, so you end up with a messy long unreadable regex like this:
const regex = /^(?<line>\d+)\s+(?<quantity>[\d.]+)\s+(?<item_unit>\d+-\d+-D\d+)\s+(?<price>[\d.]+)\s+(?<amount>[\d.]+)\s+(?:EA\s(?<item_name_v1>[^\r\n]*)\s+|(?<item_name_v2>[^\r\n]*)\nEA\s+)Drawing:\s+(?<drawing>[^\r\n]+)\s+Due:\s+(?:Requester:\s+(?<req_date_v1>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s+(?<req_name_v1>[^\r\n]+)|(?<req_date_v2>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\sRequester:\s+(?<req_name_v2>[^\r\n]+))\s+Order:\s+(?<order>\w+-\d+-\d+)\s+Seq\sNo:\s+(?<seq_no>\d+)$/gm;

const input = `Purchase Order
37224
(omitted details)
Total Purchase Order 0.00
PO Terms
Freight Terms:
Ship Via: FOB:
Terms:
N/A
Net 30 Days Best Way Destination
Line Quantity Item Unit Price Amount
U/M
1 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
EA LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: Requester:
05/19/2023 NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9002
2 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
EA LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9002
3 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
EA
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9003
4 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
EA SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9003
Total 0.00
(omitted details)
Page 1 of 1`;

// Loop over all matches.
for (const match of input.matchAll(regex)) {
  // An object to store all the captured groups.
  let foundData = {};
  // Loop over all captured groups.
  for (const group of Object.entries(match.groups)) {
    let name = group[0];
    let value = group[1];
    // A regex to test if it's a group with a _v1 or _v2 at the end.
    let matchMultiNamedGroup = name.match(/^(.*?)_(v\d)$/)
    if (matchMultiNamedGroup) {
      // If it's _v2, we've already handled it in the step before for _v1.
      if (matchMultiNamedGroup[2] === "v2") continue;
      // Remove the _v1 for the capturing group name.
      name = matchMultiNamedGroup[1];
      // Take the value if it's not undefined or take the capturing group _v2 instead.
      value = value !== undefined ? value : match.groups[matchMultiNamedGroup[1] + '_v2'];
    }
    // Add the group to the data object.
    foundData[name] = value;
  }
  console.log(foundData);
}
```

But the good news is that it seems that C# accepts to have a named
capturing group several times in the pattern. And this helps us in
this situation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M8zHBj

Comment: I just stumbled upon the named groups thing and made a little progress myself. but the way you have shown is super nice. never thought to make 1 big match then filter through the lines.

Comment: @Jfisher387: thanks! Hope it helps you quickly extract what you need.

Comment: Maybe you can combine it with the basic idea of this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vdOeVj

Comment: I was tinkering with this and I'm a little confused on implementation of this method. I think i would have 2 patterns, and use the captured substring of the first match to be the input text for the second but I get a parsing error.

Comment: @Fildor: you made a great job of programming all that for @Jfisher387. Just be careful with the search of `U/M` without new lines around it, as it could be somewhere else in the text, such as in the item description. Same thing for `Total` as you could have this word in the description also.

Comment: @Jfisher387 : The step 1 isn't really needed, as my pattern at step 2 will work with all the initial input text. But as we don't know how long it is (you've especially omitted some details), I proposed to reduce the input data first, to make it run faster at step 2. About your errors, could you produce a .NET fiddle project to show us what isn't working?

Comment: @PatrickJanser I know. It's supposed to just be a coarse example. See it as placeholders for "find out where to cut".

Comment: @Jfisher387 : I just thought about step 1, where I extract the interesting data. I edited my answer and replaced `\n` by `\r?\n` in order to handle either Windows or Linux line endings. Probably your input was using Windows CRLF and not LF.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCSNtm here is my fiddle link. never used this before, and it seems to have issues with some lines because I only uploaded the one file, this is a windows app so its missing some files.

Comment: @Jfisher387 : Use the new regex for step 1, using `\r?\n`. And at step 2, you forgot to activate the `x` flag. Use the Regex101 *code generator* button on the left, from my link, and you'll see that you have to add `RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline;`. The comments in the pattern should stay in your app, for clarity!

Comment: @Jfisher387 : See the second step working here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/kh6XR0

Comment: That seems like a really elagent way to handle that. Appreciate you taking the time to walk me through this much. Now I'm going to look into it further and then move to get the remaining data to show up

Comment: @Jfisher387: Welcome! By the way, I just changed the example to handle this problematic of two capturing groups for the same value, depending on the order. I also removed the group "0" in the output: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dgemsj

Comment: @Jfisher387 : Oh, and I discovered that if your pattern has twice the same group name, well, it's the first one that matches that will fill it, so in fact, no need to do all this handling of `_v1` or `_v2`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M8zHBj is way easier. But this will probably not work with all regex engines. I think that in PCRE, a named capturing group should be unique in the pattern.

Comment: I did some testing and I got it working nearly flawlessly now thanks to you. tried another pdf and it only loses line item 10. not quite sure yet how but only took a few tweeks on the part number to get it working.

Comment: @PatrickJanser the issue i run into at this point is it cut the 1 line off 1 line early and put it on the next page which put text inbetween. is there a easy workaround for something like this? i think if instead of using the $ to find end of line if i can fine the seq no: instead it would better encapsulate, but then theres a possibility that there is a bunch of random characters inside of a match. which i think would throw off the rest of the matches?

Comment: @Jfisher387 : Well, without seeing what your input text is from the *PDF to text* tool, it's rather difficult to adapt the regular expression. It might be a good idea to extract the interesting data first, if it's multi-paged and concatenate it in a new variable which then will be readable with the pattern we already set up. **Could you create some input samples and add them to your question?** Normally, I think that blocks of code with either 3 blank spaces before or using the triple backticks notation (documented by stackoverflow) should do the trick.

Comment: @PatrickJanser edited my question to include another PO with more lines that extends to 3 pages. all works perfectly except for po line #10 which is halfways on page 2 and the beginning of page 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253896/discussion-between-patrick-janser-and-jfisher387).